# Ubuntu 21.04 doesn't detect my webcam (integrated), since a week ago

Tags: webcam, 21.04

My cam was even working the last week, but now I tried to make a videocall on Discord and it tolds me (camera undetected), I tested on cheese app and it says the same.

Any ideas??

OS: Ubuntu 21.04
Laptop: MSI
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7

EDIT: `lsusb` gives

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1122 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Does your camera show up if you do `lsusb`?

Comment: I have this:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1038:1122 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries KLC
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Apparently...it's not there

Comment: Nope, it's not there. But it may have been turned off in the BIOS settings.

Comment: Ok nvm, it was a key where you can lock the cam via software (fn + F6). There's no an advise or warning where you can see that.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. Accepting your own answer is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok nvm, it was a key where you can lock the cam via software (fn + F6) on the laptop. There's no an advise or warning where you can see that. Thanks to Jos to try to help me (and actually he did it :) )